# Show user post count while using "ultimate member" and "co-author"

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the plugin ultimate member and co-author
and in the author page in the post tab
i'm trying to show the numbers of posts the user has written with this line

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'author',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $user_login
        )
    ),
);
$author_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $author_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $author_query->have_posts() ) : $author_query->the_post();

    // Do your presentation

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Would appreciate your help for the correct code

Answer (score 0):

You will need a counter.

```
   $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'author',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $user_login
                )
            ),
        );
        $author_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        $count=0;

        if ( $author_query->have_posts() ) :  
            while ( $author_query->have_posts() ) : $author_query->the_post();

            // Do your presentation

             $count++; 

           endwhile;

        endif;

 echo $count;
```

Comment: it's returning the number zero on all the author post page.

Comment: Maybe the $args are wrong.just  try the loop without tax query . If it works , take the current user Id and give it as parameter to term

Comment: the problem as it turns out the ultimate member plugin redirect visitor from the author page to a custom page so the user id doesn't work